# Specifying a Docker base image that only runs on Windows

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I'm planning on only running my images as Linux containers on a Windows server host OS. From what I understand, the Docker file below will create a multi-arch image that will run on both a Windows and a Linux host OS.

Is it possible to reduce the image size by specifying that the image will only run on a Windows host OS? Which base image should I use to achieve this?

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
    
# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
    
# Copy everything else and build
COPY ../engine/examples ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
    
# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

Comment: You can't run a linux container on windows as such. You can run one on WSL, which is basically linux running in a VM in windows.  When we talk about multi-arch, we are referring to processor architecture, not host OS. Finally, although people do run windows containers, docker is primarily a linux technology and you'd be best advised to run it on a linux host rather than a windows host. Most orgs avoid windows containers because they weigh in at the GB range rather than the MB range of linux containers.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up what multi-arch is! I wasn't talking about Windows containers though, but rather Linux containers running on Windows. Is this also not advised for production? The size of the containers will still be relatively small as far as I can tell

Comment: To clarify, is it not advised to run Linux containers on WSL in a production environment?

Comment: For clarity -- you cannot run linux containers in windows. Linux containers share a linux kernel, so you must be running in Linux for it to work. Docker for Windows runs a linux VM, and so does WSL.